# Learning Objective-c without knowing C

Tags: objective-c

I'm planning to learn Objective C. Most of the books say that the reader should know C as a starting point.
Is it necessary to know C before diving in the Objective-C ocean ? I'm a ruby programmer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally think you should be fine diving in without C. Yes, Objective-C is a superset of C, but that doesn't that all Objective-C coding will require C knowledge. The situation is similar for C++. I say if you have a firm knowledge of at least one programming language and know the basics of C's constructs and syntax you should be fine to *start* the other stuff. You don't need to be able to write strong C applications before you get started with Obj-C, but it will help you a lot once you can.

If you find you need to do something that requires deeper C-knowledge, then you can hit the C manual a bit harder, but it probably isn't necessary until you get to that point. You should be able to develop your experience of the two languages pretty simultaneously instead of having to learn C for a month before you can even touch Objective-C. :D

Here's what the Objective-C books want you to know about C:

- typing system. Pointers, arrays, structs
- functions.
- general design and organization of programs.

Since you're a ruby programmer, most of this should come fairly easily. The biggest shock is going to be moving from a high-level dynamic language to a low-level static language, so be prepared for some big changes, buts its nothing you won't be able to handle.

Comment: I'm with you, but just wanted to add that sometimes there are methods in Obj-C that are C functions.

Comment: If they are methods, they are, by definition, not C functions. :) What you meant is that there are a handful of APIs that are straight C functions.

Comment: The thing is that Objective-C *is* C. When you define your normal program logic (if statements, while statements, assignments) inside a method you are always using C. The Objective-C part is only about how classes are defined and methods on them are invoked. Put differently, if you have learned Objective-C, you *have* automatically learned C.

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia -

Objective-C is a reflective, object-oriented programming language that adds Smalltalk-style messaging to the C programming language. Objective-C is a thin layer on top of C, and moreover is a strict superset of C;

**Yes** , you should have knowledge of `C`.

Answer (score 1):

As @arjan points out it's a superset of C.  You might be able to work your way though examples and such without prior C experience, however to become productive you will eventually have to understand plain C.  For examples many APIs such as SQLite access are only C (not ObjC/Cocoa).  You really have to grasp concepts such as pointers, C-style strings etc.

Comment: It isn't a subset. It's a superset. I.E. It is C with more added. A subset would be a part of C.

Answer (score 0):

You can't program in Objective-C without knowing C, as Objective-C is simply a superset of C.

Comment: Yeah it's C with a few new concepts and a horrible syntax

Comment: It's C with Smalltalk-ish stuff bolted in top of it.  In a away the C stuff and "Smalltalk" stuff stay out of each other's way.  The syntax is weird but overall ObjC is easier to grasp (IMHO) than C++

Comment: 'horrible' is a very subjective term, but it's true that from a language design standpoint it's maybe a bit remarkable that standalone functions are defined and called with a totally different syntax as functions that are part of a class.

Comment: I don't want to start a flamewar (this is whole other big debate) but one of the reasons for C++ complexity is building classes/objects on top of C structs.  Things like copy constructors, value semantics originate from that.  Yes I do like C++ but I can't deny its complexity.

Comment: There are a lot of reasons for the complexity in C++, but I'm not 100% sure that the function/method syntax is to blame here. C#, Java, heck even Javascript have the exact same syntax (well almost exact in case of Javascript ;)) and none of those complexities.

Comment: @arjan: Perhaps because calling a function and calling a method are...different?

Comment: Their difference is minor, basically the method variant gets an implicit *this* parameter. In most languages they are already distinguished from each other. I.e. in C++: object.method(a, b, c); while a function is function(a, b, c); The "object." separates the method from the function. It would not be necessary to use named parameters for methods, and positional parameters for functions, just because methods and functions are slightly different. Functions could just as well use named parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is absolutely necessary, I learnt Objective C with no knowledge of any other languages. However, saying that, it is very useful if you know C and a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

Nah.  As long as you know what functions are, variables, objects, then you'll pick up "C" syntax by programming in objective C.    To be more specific, I don't think you need to go and "learn C" first.   Rather, I'd keep a C reference handy and look up anything you don't understand there.