# What do I need to know in order to start full time IOS development?

Tags: ios

I am an experienced web developer and want to move to full time ios development. At the moment my skillset comprises of php, javascript and MySQL.

I am doing video tutorial course on ios development (lynda.com) at the moment with a motive to be able to develop ios apps that deliver basic things like keeping a track of monthly budget.

My question is - What do I need to know to be able to start full time app development? Is objective C going to be enough or do I have to learn C++ also?

I would highly appreciate your response to the questions I have.

Comment: Have you been to developer.apple.com and looked for the article on iOS that's named "Getting Started" ?

Comment: The Standford iOS dev course is excellent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only **need** to know Objective-C language. I used these tutorials when I began which I found equally useful as entertaining: [The New Boston](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=28). It begins from the basics of setting up a new project, some basic navigation through an app and you will later learn saving and loading data. After these, you will be well on your way to developing awesome apps ready for the app store.

I am sure your app to track monthly budget could be developed just through these tutorials but for more complex problems the [raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials) tutorials are great and easy to follow.

That being said, you can use C++ code in your iOS project, but that it something to look into when you absolutely have to. All in all, having a background knowledge of other C languages is great but not essential.

**EDIT:** [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4986375/1359306) other SO answer is much more detailed about the supersets of the C language and should help you out - "I say if you have a firm knowledge of at least one programming language and know the basics of C's constructs and syntax you should be fine to start the other stuff. You don't need to be able to write strong C applications before you get started with Obj-C, but it will help you a lot once you can."

All the best.

Comment: I beg to differ. There are only 3 C-family languages: C, C++ and Obj-C. Using C++ on Mac/iOS platform is possible but not recommended and you can live without it. However, knowing C is essential for every Obj-C developer since Obj-C is only a small object layer over the C language. In reality, most of the time you are using C, not Obj-C (if, for, while, NSLog - that's all plain C).

Comment: I agree but he/she can learn a huge amount of C through iOS development - like you say 'most of the time you are using C, not Obj-C'. The tutorials will teach the basics and he/she can learn some advanced C should he/she need to at a later date. For the simple monthly budget app, it is not essential (immediately). Also don't forget C influenced C#, Java, JavaScript, Perl, PHP and loads more.

Comment: Most of the tutorials skip things like `struct`, `enum`, `typedef`, `#define`, `static` (either for a global or a local variable). These are things you need almost in every project. People know how to use things like `NSLog`, `NSStringFromCGRect`, `CGRectMake` but can't declare similar functions by themselves. That's sad. I would recommend a C tutorial before Obj-C tutorial.

Comment: Thanks a lot Patrick. I do have 'rusty' knowledge of both C and C++ from my college days. Its just that I haven't used it that much on a professional level. I really appreciate everyone taking their valuable time to answer my question. Have a nice weekend ahead :)

Comment: Haha, it sounds a lot like my early days as an iOS developer with rusty C# and C++ knowledge from uni. All the best.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this web sites you can learn more.....

http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/learn-objective-c-day-1/

http://www.icodeblog.com/

http://mobileorchard.com/

but you should have knoledge on objective-c programming before

Follow below URL...

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OOP_ObjC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005149-CH1-SW2

Hope this will help you....!!!! cheers...!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm learning as well.

There's a series of free lecture courses available from Stanford University on iTunes.
I found [this one](https://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/ipad-iphone-application-development/id473757255) pariculalrly helpful.

A bit of straight C won't hurt either.